# Should I create a new file for consts?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm wondering where should I keep my constants? 
I've read about creating a new file where I can store all my constants. The problem is that more variables like that mean more code. In case of creating a big project should I create several files? Not sure. 
I also used to keep my constants in the xml file(strings.xml). 
The third option is to have those consts as top-level variables. I have noticed that when I had added such constant before the name of class Kotlin has changed that class to a file. It's uncommon for me behavior that's why I am asking. I used to store my const in Java in that class/package where I have needed them. Const in Kotlin are compile-time. Is this similar to the action of #DEFINE in C?

I hope I will solve my problems on how to properly use and store constants in Kotlin. Thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to just use separate Kotlin object file *Constants.kt*.

This will help you to manage constants at one place in a big project, particularly on scale, it'll be needed.

```
object Constants {

  object BundleKeys {
    val A = "a"
  }

  object ActivityResultCodes {
    val B = 1092
  }

  object FragmentTags {
    val C = "c"
  }

  object BundleExtraParams {
    val D = "d"
  }

}
```

This will help you to keep separate constants in separate objects inside *Constants.kt* object

So you can access those like *Constants.BundleKeys.A* or *Constants.ActivityResultCodes.B*

Comment: 1. I wouldn't. Some constants make sense together, others not. 2. If you do put them in one file, why wrap them in `object Constants`? https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/best-practices-for-top-level-declarations/219: "The recommended practice is to never use object for creating namespaces, and to always use top-level declarations when possible. We haven’t found name conflicts to be an issue, and if you do get a conflict, you can resolve it using an import with alias."

Comment: Yeah make sense!!